# changing div within another div

Tags: jquery

My html looks like:

```
<div class="cal_wrapper_top" id="event-1">
    <div class="cal_date">
        Feb 18
    </div>

    <div class="cal_events">
        Jack Johnson
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cal_wrapper" id="event-2">
    <div class="cal_date">
        Feb 19
    </div>

    <div class="cal_events">
        Jason Mraz
    </div>
</div>
```

When you hover either event-1 or event-2, I want the div within this with id=date to be bolded.

Is it possible to select this specific div?

Comment: ID is supposed to be unique. You can't reuse an ID multiple times in the same document. Use a class name instead.

Comment: always forget about that.  Even so, is it possible to then only update the class cal_date from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with plain CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/skimberk1/r645t/

Or you can do it with jQuery (although I don't know why you'd want to): http://jsfiddle.net/skimberk1/5wsPq/

Also, you can also use an ID once and only once.

EDIT: Here's an example that changes the text on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/skimberk1/qwSun/

Comment: I was going to suggest a JavaScript solution, but then you posted this. Well done, you have my +1.

Comment: nice solution!  Any thoughts on if I wanted to change the div's contents to something other than the date?

Comment: @Mike You'd have to use Javascript for that.

Comment: I honestly don't really care... I don't design for IE6 anymore, it's a waste of effort in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's expected at this point that if you need IE6 support, you state that up front.  People are busily scrubbing that out of their brains.

Comment: @Mike I added an example of code that would change the text on hover, hope it helps. If you like my answer, I would appreciate it if you accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly:

```
 $('div.cal_wrapper, div.cal_wrapper_top').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('div#date').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    //$(this).find('div.date').css('font-weight', 'bold'); //if changing to class
    //$(this).find('div[name="date"]').css('font-weight', 'bold'); //if changing to name
}, function() {
    $(this).find('div#date').css('font-weight', 'normal');
    //$(this).find('div.date').css('font-weight', 'normal'); //if changing to class
    //$(this).find('div[name="date"]').css('font-weight', 'normal'); //if changing to name
});​
```

I would be remiss to point out that the attribute `id` should be unique to a single element on the page. Quirkiness is bound to occur otherwise.

You may want to redo the html and either change the `id` to a class:

```
<div class="cal_wrapper_top" id="event-1">
    <div class="cal_date date">
        Feb 18
    </div>

    <div class="cal_events">
        Jack Johnson
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cal_wrapper" id="event-2">
    <div class="cal_date date">
        Feb 19
    </div>

    <div class="cal_events">
        Jason Mraz
    </div>
</div>​​​
```

or use the `name` attribute instead:

```
<div class="cal_wrapper_top" id="event-1">
    <div class="cal_date" name="date">
        Feb 18
    </div>

    <div class="cal_events">
        Jack Johnson
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cal_wrapper" id="event-2">
    <div class="cal_date" name="date">
        Feb 19
    </div>

    <div class="cal_events">
        Jason Mraz
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​
```

Comment: It was my understanding that the `name` attribute was only used in forms.

Comment: The `name` attribute can be used on any element (although it won't necessarily validate on just *any* element). `title` or `alt` or a custom attribute could be used just as easily. If this were my project, I would use `class`.

Comment: I have been trying to convince anyone that'll listen that class selectors are only a little slower than IDs on modern browsers, and what's more, they are CORRECT.  IDs stop working as your requirements change, but classes are good basically forever.  Moral of the story:  Benchmark before doing something weird.